# AppScript: How to create an upload form?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am developing an Add-on for Gmail using AppScript. 
My objective is to create something similar to the image below. Any hints?

[image: upload image]

Comment: Are you developing it? If that's the case, would you mind sharing a sample of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 6):

**Problem**

File upload in Gmail Add-ons. In short - not exactly. Gmail Add-ons use `CardService` class to build the Ui - and it doesn't have a `file` input type, nor any drag-and-drop functionality. But there is a workaround.

**Step 1. Create trigger widget**

Then, ensure that your `Card` contains a `CardSection` with an `ImageButton`, `TextButton` or `KeyValue` widget (`KeyValue` is deprecated, use [`DecoratedText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/decorated-text)) that has an `OpenLink` action set on them. When using the `setUrl(url)` method to setup URL to open on widget click, use the current project's URL (when deploying both as WebApp and Add-on) that can be accessed dynamically via `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` call.

**Step 2. Create file submit form**

In the Add-on project, create an Html file that will handle the file upload. You can use sample one or create your own implementation. the sample file uses `FileReader` Web API to handle the submitted file (note that client-to-server communication in Google Apps Script requires preventing `submit` event handler and calling a server-side function via `goolge.script.run` API only).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="file" type="file" />
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Save file</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      var form = document.forms[0];
      
      form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var file = form.elements[0].files[0];
        
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        reader.onload = () => { 
          var buffer = reader.result;
          
          var data = Array.from(new Int8Array(buffer));
          
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((server) => {
            top.window.close();
          }).saveFile(data,file.name,file.type);
        };
      });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3. Setup doGet()**

In your WebApp code, add the required `doGet()` function that will show the file upload form that we created during step 2. It can be as simple as a couple lines of code (just make sure to return the html file parsed by `HtmlService`):

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('file name from step 2');
  return html;
}
```

**Step 4. Handle file upload**

In your WebApp code, add handler that will receive file data (this sample assumes you read it as byte[], see step 2 for details).

```
function saveFile(upload,name,mime) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(upload,mime,name);
  
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  Logger.log(file.getUrl()) //test upload;

  //handle file as needed;
  return;
}
```

**Step 5. Deploy as WebApp**

Lastly, you will have to deploy your Add-on as both WebApp (or bundle with one) and an Add-on. Assuming you've already configured manifest for the Add-on, go to "Publish" menu, select "Deploy as web app", create a deployment and allow access to anyone.

**Notes**

1. This method won't allow you to easily update the Ui to show which files were uploaded, but you can add a `withSuccessHandler()` call to `google.script.run` that on successful server-side handling of the uploaded file closes the window with the form, save state info to cache / user properties. Then, if you set the `OpenLink`'s `OnClose` property to `RELOAD_ADD_ON` (see step 1), you will be able to conditionally update Ui to notify the user of successful upload.
2. **UPDATE**: after Tanaike's comment I reworked the upload process to better handle files: changed binary string file read to `ArrayBuffer` transformed to `Int8Array` and uploaded as an `Array` instance.
3. Current issue is the `.g*` files upload (despite correct transfer). Will update the answer when solved.

**References**

1. `OpenLink` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-link);
2. `FileReader` Web API [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) on MDN;
3. `newBlob()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(String)) (`Utilities` class);
4. Client-to-server communication in GAS [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication);
5. Creating and serving HTML in GAS [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html);
6. Web Apps [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web);

Comment: In your script, the text file can be uploaded. But when the binary file (for example, you can test it with a zip file.) is uploaded, the data is different from the original file, because of the problem of character code. By this, for example, when the data is created as a file in Google Drive, the file cannot be opened. Please be careful this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! True, the initial script was far from perfect, thank you! I've updated it to handle files correctly, upload tested for binary files as well as text and image files - works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think that it will be useful for OP and other users.

Comment: @OlegValter, an indeed a very nicely written and detailed answer. It helped me in my project with similar requirements. I am having an issue when updating the code. I make any change to the HTML file but the code will keep on getting the old web app URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @AwaisUmar - glad to hear that my answer was useful to you! The issue is most likely due to the fact that you need to redeploy the web app each time you change html file (each deployments uses a snapshot of apps script project files) - (if you need to preview changes, just use the /dev URL instead)

Comment: @OlegValter, that's right, dev url worked. I have extended your idea and implemented an upload form. Is there any way to push a card to the stack when the files are uploaded? I have tried to use the navigation but its not working. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AwaisUmar - sorry for the slow response, I don't visit SO much lately :( You "can" (as a workaround) implement the flow: 1. persist filename(s) + any state info you want to preserve 2. reload add-on 3. add a cond. to initializer function that checks for persisted filenames and loads card with persisted names and state (as far as I know, there is no way currently to let GSuite Add-ons know of the outside world changes)

Comment: @OlegValter that's okay. I had to do a lot of head scratch but I implemented the same flow. Just a beginner of appscript here. Thank you :)

Comment: @AwaisUmar - good to hear that you were successful in implementing the flow :) Good luck with further projects (btw, take a look at the latest [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/) Google added a lot of new features for Gmail's `CardService`)

Comment: @OlegValter thank you!!! I keep on coming back here. I need to send a REST API call to send those attached files after user attaches them from the html form, comes back to the card and hits a "send" button. Can't store the files in properties because of the limitation on data storage. So I am first creating the files in drive temporarily, making the API call and then deleting those files after the successful response from the API call. It seems to be a very hacky way but couldn't' find any other solution to it; cleaner one. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @AwaisUmar - hm, quite a flow you have here - I don't think there is a much cleaner way to do it with GAS since what you've described is a server acting on behalf of the user. To my knowledge, `DriveApp` (or direct Drive API call) is the only way to implement flows invloving filesystem access in GAS (given that you need to persist files until user comes back to the card - I would probably do the same you did :). That's definitely a hack, but until we get a file input type...

Comment: @OlegValter file input type should be introduced. I agree. Thank you for your continual help. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @AwaisUmar - probably will get it some time (we got date & time pickers after all).
My pleasure :)

Comment: @OlegValter sorry for reaching you out again. Please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668319/log-in-to-an-external-site-from-gmail-addon

Comment: @AwaisUmar - sure, in fact, the short version is - yes, you can, longer v in q)